# wsdl works fine in SoapUI but receives exception when accessed through client

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have client wsdl which works well, when tried to invoke through soap-UI, I need to call it through web service client code, hence I generated source code with 'wsimport' and tried to invoke it again, but it return following error:

```
17:28:20,594 ERROR [CommonClient] Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation: 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unprocessed 'mustUnderstand' header element: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.getSOAPFaultException(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding.SOAP11BindingJAXWS.throwFaultException(SOAP11BindingJAXWS.java:107)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAP11Binding.verifyUnderstoodHeader(CommonSOAP11Binding.java:86)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.checkMustUnderstand(CommonSOAPBinding.java:994)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:385)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:232)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy866.getAllowableActions(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.web.services.User.getUsrData(UserResource.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:217)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:206)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:514)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:491)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:200)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
```

kindly help me on this. Source code is:

```
@Path("/users")

@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public class User {


    @GET
    @Path("/getdata/{param1}/{param2}")
    public Response getUsrData(@PathParam("param1") String param1,@PathParam("param2") String param2) {




        try {           
             <calling api from wsimport generated code and passing parameters to it.>
```

Comment: Can you add your request header into the question?

Comment: @Ronixus  When I runs this code, it logs request created which works well with SoapUI. but it has not header: "<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body>"

Comment: Actually the part that you didn't put is important, show the entire method if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Actually I need to to add header with login credentials.

```
<wsse:Security>
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>Joe</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>Java</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```